# What is the difference between apex REST and SOAP API and global REST and SOAP API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api

Apex REST and Apex SOAP are not strictly speaking APIs, but they’re ways that you can expose your Apex objects so what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) SFDC as a platform exposes itself via REST and SOAP API. This is what you are referring to as "global REST and SOAP API".

2) If the standard APIs don't get you where you need to go, you can expose custom Apex as either REST or SOAP.

The difference here has to do with flexibility. When you expose your Apex as REST or SOAP you have control, its your own custom web service.

Comment: That mean standard REST and SOAP API do not provide way for  Apex to expose your class as to any other language.

Comment: I suppose you could say that. If you want to expose your class to the world, you either do it as a web service via REST or SOAP, or, you can invoke your apex via inbound email service. A public force.com site could also run apex behind VF, with some limitations.